# Regarding getting the rowsum of a python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

I have following python data frame

```
data={'1':[1,1,1,1],'2':[1,1,1,1],'3':[1,1,1,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I need to get the **sum of the rows** in a such away that my **final output should be like this,**

[image]

So in this desired output, the second column should contain the row sum up to second column of the original data frame. So on.

To get this output, I wrote the following code,

```
sum_mat=np.zeros(shape=(3,3))

numOfIteration=3
itr=list(range(0,numOfIteration))

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        while i <= itr[i]:
            sum_mat[i,j]+= df.iloc[i,j]

print (sum_mat)
```

I am not getting an output here because the code is running forever (may be an infinite loop).

Can anyone suggest anything to get the desired output ?

May be there is more effective and easier way to do the same thing.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**
i update the for loop as follows,

```
for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
        while i <= itr[i]:
           sum_mat[i,j] = df.iloc[:,0:i].sum(axis=1)
```

but it gives following error,

```
sum_mat[i,j] = df.iloc[:,0:i].sum(axis=1)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 2):

this could work also

```
for i,row in df.iterrows(): #go through each row
    df.loc[i]=df.loc[i].cumsum() #assign each row as the cumulative sum of the row
```

output:

```
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
```

EDIT

can just do :

```
df=df.cumsum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum_mat=np.zeros(shape=(3,3))

numOfIteration=3
itr=list(range(0,numOfIteration))

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
            if j==0:
               sum_mat[i,0]=df.iloc[i,0]
            else:
               sum_mat[i,j]=df.iloc[i,j]+sum_mat[i,j-1]

print (sum_mat)
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Use [cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) function to find the cumulative sum of the values seen so far along the column axis.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'1': [1, 1, 1, 1], '2': [1, 1, 1, 1], '3': [1, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("before")
print(df)

df = df.cumsum(axis=1)
print("after")
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

before

```
   1  2  3
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  1  1  1
```

after

```
   1  2  3
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
```